# Can cats make hiking companions?

Tags: hiking, pets, walking

So, cats are known for being good companions to writers and [programmers](http://www.lolcats.com/)… But are they any good for hiking, or at least going out for a walk?

The usual cat is portrayed as lying down on some cozy cushion. However, cats that live in flats usually get “craziness moments” with intense physical activity, and cats living in the countryside are definitely active. I therefore don't think it couldn't handle a walk, though there's maybe a walking distance limit.

The main problem, though, is about the animal's fundamental independence and lack of obedience. A dog will usually follow its master pretty easily, but cats definitely don't obey you, and can flee quickly when afraid, which can happen often. Coercion is probably not an option, since most cats won't accept a leash.

So:

- does anyone know of a cat that would accompany its master for a walk?
- for a hike?
- is there an inherent limitation to the distance it can walk?
- what advice could be used to make sure it doesn't get lost?
- as a last option, is there any kind of carrying bag that could allow transporting the animal during a walk?

Comment: Hi Matti, welcome to Travel.SE. Well, you've been around here for a while already. Questions on this site are expected to fall within the scope as defined in [our FAQ](http://travel.stackexchange.com/faq#questions). However, there could certainly be a place for your question, for instance, in the proposed [The Great Outdoors SE proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3659/the-great-outdoors). That proposal is close to finishing its commitment stage so throw your weight behind it you're interested!

Comment: Yup, I knew it was pretty close to the limits of the scope, but wasn't sure and had not found anything close on SE. Didn't think about digging in A51, sorry. Thanks for the redirection!

Comment: It's interesting but it's definitely more about cats than about travel. Sadly we don't seem to have either a Cats or Pets proposal. I think looking for a cat lovers forum rather than a travel Q&A site will help you find an answer. But maybe one of the breeds with more dog-like characteristics, like a Manx??

Comment: Actually I'm wrong there are two proposals that might work with this question. I suggest following or committing to one or both. If it's in the definition phase you can even pose an example question: **[Pets](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5489/pets)** and **[Animal Health and Behavior](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11526/animal-health-and-behavior)**.

Comment: @hippietrail The Great Outdoors proposal Ankur referred to seems like a good place for this question  :)  I should have thought more before asking it here, it was indeed not a good place for it.

Comment: @hippietrail so you'd say it's more about pets than about hiking? Well, maybe so… That's not at all how I had conceived it. To me, it was more along the lines of "how can I keep hiking if I'm supposed to have a cat with me?" rather than "how can I make a cat walk?", but it does sound more like the second one on a second reading…

Comment: I thought it might be "Is there a breed of cat suitable as a hiking companion?" In any case it seems cat experts would be more likely to have an answer well that travel experts. But yes The proposal Ankur suggested is definitely another good idea!

Comment: I know this has been closed, but I still need to drop in [this link](http://cuteoverload.com/2010/05/11/lets-go-for-a-catwalk/) - cats can make great hiking buddies!